# Pytorch Lightning: Loaded model gives poor performance when tested on same validation data

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, pytorch-lightning

I am training a model using Pytorch lightning, and then testing the best model in another script. As a sanity checking excercise, I am testing with the same data as I used for validation in training. The model should be getting a PSNR score of 37 dB but I am getting a score of 25 dB.

Here is how I load my model for testing:

```
checkpoint = "/.../my_location/model_name.ckpt"
model = LightningResunet2.load_from_checkpoint(checkpoint, strict=True)
```

Here is the Pytorch lightning definition:

```
class LightningResunet2(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters(logger=False)
        self.model = network(in_nc=6, out_nc=3, nc=96, nb=20, act_mode='BR')
        self.custom_loss = fixed_loss()

    def forward(self, x):
        prediction, noise_map = self.model(x)
        return prediction, noise_map

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        noisy, clean_img, sigma_img, if_asym = batch
        output, predicted_noise = self.model(noisy)
        loss = self.custom_loss(output, clean_img, predicted_noise, sigma_img, if_asym)
        self.log("train_loss", loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        return loss

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=2e-4, eps=1e-8)
        scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, 4000,
                                                                        eta_min=float(1e-6))
        scheduler.step()
        return [optimizer], [scheduler]

    def validation_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        noisy, clean = batch
        output, _ = self.model(noisy)
        val_loss = F.l1_loss(output, clean)
        psnr = test_psnr(clean, output)
        
        self.log("validation_loss", val_loss, on_epoch=True, on_step=False, sync_dist=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        self.log("validation_psnr", psnr, on_epoch=True, on_step=False, sync_dist=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        return {'val_loss': val_loss, 'val_psnr': psnr}

    def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        noisy, clean = batch
        output, _ = self.model(noisy)
        psnr = test_psnr(clean, output)
        self.log("validation_psnr", psnr, on_epoch=True, on_step=False, sync_dist=True, prog_bar=True, logger=True)
        return {'val_psnr': psnr}
```

I have triple checked that the models are the same, and the data is the same. I have used this script before to check model performance and it worked fine. My most recent model uses a custom batch norm function. I suspect this might be causing the problem.

Here is my model definition:

```
class DnCNN_lightning(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, in_nc=6, out_nc=3, nc=64, nb=20, act_mode='BR'):
        super(DnCNN_lightning, self).__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters(logger=False)
        assert 'R' in act_mode or 'L' in act_mode

        bias = False
        self.fcn = FCN()
        dncnn1 = dncnn_block(nc, nc, nc)
        head1 = conv(in_nc, nc, mode='C'+act_mode[-1], bias=bias, kernel_size=5,padding=2,)
        # head1 = conv(in_nc, nc, mode='C'+act_mode[-1], bias=bias)
        tail1 = conv(nc, out_nc, mode='C', bias=bias)
        self.model1 = sequential(head1, dncnn1, tail1)

    def forward(self, x, train_mode=True):
        noise_level = self.fcn(x)
        concat_img = torch.cat([x, noise_level], 1)
        level1_out = self.model1(concat_img) + x
        return level1_out, noise_level
```

I don't want to confuse things by including every submodule. However the batchnorm layers within my network are custom. The function below defines the new BN which is defined as a pytorch class:

```
class BFBatchNorm2d(nn.BatchNorm2d):
    def __init__(self, num_features, eps=1e-5, momentum=0.1, use_bias = False, affine=True):
        super(BFBatchNorm2d, self).__init__(num_features, eps, momentum)
        self.use_bias = use_bias

    def forward(self, x):
        self._check_input_dim(x)
        y = x.transpose(0,1)
        return_shape = y.shape
        y = y.contiguous().view(x.size(1), -1)
        if self.use_bias:
            mu = y.mean(dim=1)
        sigma2 = y.var(dim=1)

        if self.training is not True:
            if self.use_bias:
                y = y - self.running_mean.view(-1, 1)
            y = y / ( self.running_var.view(-1, 1)**0.5 + self.eps)
        else:
            if self.track_running_stats is True:
                with torch.no_grad():
                    if self.use_bias:
                        self.running_mean = (1-self.momentum)*self.running_mean + self.momentum * mu
                    self.running_var = (1-self.momentum)*self.running_var + self.momentum * sigma2
            if self.use_bias:
                y = y - mu.view(-1,1)
            y = y / (sigma2.view(-1,1)**.5 + self.eps)

        if self.affine:
            y = self.weight.view(-1, 1) * y;
            if self.use_bias:
                y += self.bias.view(-1, 1)

        return y.view(return_shape).transpose(0,1)
```

Any suggestions as to how I can troubleshoot this issue would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi Bled. Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting a similar problem.